# PI3D texturing an imported obj model as if it were an elevationmap

Tags: python, python-3.x, blender

I'm trying to create a simple train simulator using pi3d, I need to use an obj file for the map and apply textures but when I run 'set_draw_details' and apply a few textures which work fine on an elevationmap, I get a mess. (see image below)
[image]

The idea is to just have a rough grass-texture effect, but it's messing it up and stretching the texture in only 1 axis on lots of the triangles, creating the effect seen in the image.
I want to apply the same texture all over the model, as the material colours will still show, so it will also be a good texture for the ballast.

Whatever values I put in for set_draw_details seem to create the same effect.

I've got no idea how I would apply the textures from blender, whatever settings I use when exporting from blender also has the same effect (with/without vertex normals, with/without texture UVs)

```
self.map = pi3d.Model(file_string="%s.obj"%name)
self.map.set_draw_details(shader=self.shader, textures=[self.mountimg1, self.mountimg1, self.bumpimg], ntiles=1.280, shiny=0.0, umult=1.0, vmult=1.0, bump_factor=1.0)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it - I'm not too bothered by how large or small the textured dots come out, so long as they're not streaks like they currently are.

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to get this sorted out? It looks to be a UV issue - if you have a link to the obj file I could tell for certain.

In blender have you generated the UV values and do they look sensible? You need to switch to edit mode (tab) then select all vertices (A) then open UV menu (U) then choose a suitable projection. If you don't do that first then when you export to obj you won't get sensible values for mapping the texture.

In pi3d the umult and vmult arguments to set_draw_details() will control how many times the texture is mapped over the 0.0 to 1.0 range of u and v.

Sorry this reply is rather late, maybe it will help others who come across this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @paddyg's, that answer is exactly what's needed - now I just have to tweak the texture `vmult` and `umult` values until it looks right, and try different UV mapping values until it works.

Note for anyone else trying this: the 'edit' tab in Blender is a drop-down menu in the top left of the window, default value is 'object mode', and this needs to be set to 'edit mode', then there are 3 buttons, and the 'vertex selection' one needs to be selected (press 'a' to select all vertices), before pressing 'u' to open UV menu - see pictures.

Blender's user interface:

[image: edit menu]
[image: Blender window in edit mode]

Train simulator game with fixed UV mapping:

[image: train simulator texture mapping]